# Why GuzzleHttp client throws ClientException when using it to make network request on Laravel/Lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, microservices, lumen

I am currently building a Financial micro service application using Laravel/Lumen micro framework.Everything have been working perfectly as expected. My problem now is that i am trying to make a network request to my internal services via Api call from `ApiGateway` using `GuzzleHttp` client. The problem is that when i make request to the internal service, it always throws an exception of **ClientException**.

> **ClientException**.
>
> Client error: `GET http://127.0.0.1:8081/v1/admin` resulted in a `401
>   Unauthorized` response: {"error":"Unauthorized.","code":401}

I have tried to make network request to the same internal services using **postman**; and it works fine. However, for some reason still fail to work with `GuzzleHttp`. I don't know what i am doing wrong. Please your assist will be appreciated.

**Here is the httpClient.php in ApiGateway.**

```
//Constructor method
public function __construct() {
    $this->baseUri = config('services.auth_admin.base_uri');
}

public function httpRequest($method, $requestUrl, $formParams = [], $headers = []) {
    //Instantiate the GazzleHttp Client
    $client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => $this->baseUri,
    ]);
    //Send the request
    $response = $client->request($method, $requestUrl, ['form_params' => $formParams, 'headers' => $headers]);
    //Return a response
    return $response->getBody();
}

//Internal Service Communication in ApiGateway** 
public function getAdmin($header) {
    return $this->httpRequest('GET', 'admin', $header);
}
```

**InternalServiceController.php**

```
   public function getAdmin(Request $request) {
        return $this->successResponse($this->authAdminService->getAdmin($request->header()));
    }
```

> I am using Lumen version: 5.8 and GuzzleHttp Version: 6.3

Comment: The 401 error means you are not authenticated, sounds like you need to send your API token with the request.

Comment: Thats why am confuse; the request header contain valid token when i dd($request->header()) and the internal client is expecting the token to be on request header.

Comment: Can you include that headers array thats being passed into the method?

Comment: Can you change 
$client->request($method, $requestUrl, ['form_params' => $formParams, 'headers' => $headers]) to
$client->request($method, $requestUrl, ['query' => $formParams, 'headers' => $headers])

when you use with GET method?

Comment: Does the API require data in json format? if yes, are you passing application/json as content-type? If yes still, then using `form_params` will not help you. You should instead be using `json`. Beyond this, is the authentication basic? if yes, then your header should be in this format, `$header['Authorization'] = "Basic ".base64_encode('your_api_key:your_api_secret_here');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass your headers as formParams (third index instead of fourth).

Try below:

```
return $this->httpRequest('GET', 'admin', [], $header);
```

Comment: Yes, i understand exactly; I have tried it but still didn't work.

Comment: Could you update your sample so we can see that you understand? - hard to help based on sample code with an error

Comment: Thanks for your answer; it was very helpful then; I just came back to accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am making some assumptions here which I hope should be helpful to you.

PHP does not support skipping optional parameters and thus you should pass an empty array [] when calling `httpRequest()`.

```
public function httpRequest($method, $requestUrl, $formParams = [], $headers = [], $type='json', $verify = false) {
    //Instantiate the GazzleHttp Client
    $client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => $this->baseUri,
    ]);

    //the request payload to be sent
    $payload = [];

    if (!$verify) {
       $payload['verify'] = $verify; //basically for SSL and TLS
    }

    //add the body to the specified payload type
    $payload[$type] = $formParams;

    //check if any headers have been passed and add it as well
    if(count($headers) > 0) {
        $payload['headers'] = $headers;
    }

    //Send the request
    $response = $client->request($method, $requestUrl, $payload);
    //Return a response
    return $response->getBody();
}
```

Now you need to call it in this manner when you are not passing in any form_params or body

```
//Internal Service Communication in ApiGateway** 
 public function getAdmin($header) {
     return $this->httpRequest('GET', 'admin', [], $header);
 }
```